# How do I extract a property based on the contents of a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read out the values from a jStorage JSON object called data.shake (val1 .. val6 properties), but cant figure the right syntax out so that it runs correctly. for example the console log output doesnt show the value stored in it.

```
var sports = {1:'val1',2:'val2',3:'val3',
              4:'val4',5:'val5',6:'val6'};

    for (sport in sports) {
        if ('data.shake.'+sports[sport] != 0) { 
             console.log(sports[sport]+':'+'data.shake.'+sports[sport])
             //output: val1:data.shake.val1 
        }
     }
```

Comment: I have the feeling someone will tell you to use `eval`. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably mean this:

```
data.shake[sports[sport]]
```

You can't just use a string (e.g. `'data.shake.` and expect Javascript to turn this into a variable for you. You're effectively doing this:

```
if ('data.shake.val1' != 0) {
```

Obviously that condition will always pass, because non-empty strings (except `"0"`) are not equal to `0`

The syntax you need uses the [square bracket member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), which allows you to access an object's members using the result of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess at what you are trying to do with the code you provided:

```
var sports = {1:'val1',2:'val2',3:'val3',
              4:'val4',5:'val5',6:'val6'};
var data = {
    shake: {val1: 'some data', val2: 'some other data'}
};

for (sport in sports) {
    if (data.shake[sports[sport]] !== undefined) {
         console.log(sports[sport]+':'+ data.shake[sports[sport]])
    }
 }
```

You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LseUp/

Hope it helps!